# Do résumés written in LaTeX show more promise when applying to graduate schools?

Tags: graduate-admissions, cv, software, latex, formatting

I am a computer science student from India. I noticed that most of the résumés and thesis papers etc. I see are written in LaTeX.

If I write my résumé in Word (say) rather than LaTeX, will it have a negative affect when I apply to graduate schools in the U.S.?

If not, then should I even learn LaTeX for my future academic prospects?

Comment: I certainly recommend learning LaTeX at some point. I don't know the answer to your first question, but why not start learning LaTeX while you have the chance? You can google "latex resume template" to get started.

Comment: If you just submit the PDF, how would anyone even know?

Comment: @AustinHenley the default Word document appearance and the default LaTeX appearance are quite distinctive. It's true that you can tweak settings in both so that only the trained eye will notice, but it's hard not to notice a defaultish Word document.

Comment: @Anonymous I totally agree with you. In fact I would learn it someday. But is learning LaTeX just a skill? Or is it a necessity?

Comment: I think the content is more important than the appearance by orders of magnitude for a résumé.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi if you really believe that, then crayon is just about as good as latex or word

Comment: Would you mean explaining your reasoning @emory? If thing A is much more important than thing B, this automatically means that thing B is utterly unimportant? Obviously presentation is not entirely unimportant, it doesn't change the fact that the content is much, much more important.

Comment: Using the document class [`moderncv`](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv) you get a nice CV with little more skill than installing LaTeX, working from a [template](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/examples/template.tex) and compiling the result.

Comment: @AustinHenley Of course they would know! At least if they know LaTeX. It is quite easy to distinguish a PDF created by Word or LaTeX.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi if the OP has no latex experience then it will take some time to learn.  If content is "orders of magnitude" more important than appearance this time would be better spent elsewhere.  However, since in many departments latex is a standard, latex skill might be properly classified as "content".

Comment: I used Word for my CV for many years after grad school, just because I had started with Word for whatever reason I now forget, and was too lazy to reformat everything in TeX for a long time.  So I imagine quite a few people in math/CS still have CVs in Word for possibly similar reasons.

Comment: If you're looking to apply to graduate school it's not going to worry anyone what you use to write your CV (AKA resume, but I'm in the UK). The time spent learning would be better spent on refining and proofreading the content.  *But, as soon as you have a need, learn it*.  That might be for assessed work as an undergrad or internal reports etc. once you're in grad school.  There are many tools of use to CS authors, even if you don't write much maths, and when it comes down to it, it's just a markup language, which shouldn't be too hard for someone from a CS background to pick up.

Comment: This is much more minor, but I love having a LaTeX resumé, because it lets me write a huge, annotated resumé, and then comment out the parts not relevant to the job to which I"m applying.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer exactly; I maintain a single CV.tex file with internal switches for `specialty_A`, `specialty_B`, etc. Best thing I ever did to make sure I don't send out something accidentally outdated.

Comment: @emory. Didn't Feynman write a letter of recommendation on a napkin with a crayon one time? Content matters more than medium.

Comment: @MadPhysicist It would not surprise me.  I remember as a graduate student buying a box of crayons after reading about something Feynman did.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In a math-heavy area the ability to use LaTeX certainly matters, yet it's just another skill. In other words, if your resume says that you are familiar with LaTeX, then you don't need to prove it by typesetting your document in it.

However, for two candidates that are equivalent but for LaTeX familiarity, in a math-heavy area I would certainly pick the one with the skill. Working with the other on a paper will probably be a nuisance at first, wasting valuable time. Moreover, how in the world he/she survived with no familiarity of LaTeX until now? It's a bit like being a programmer and not using a version control.

**Edit:**

Just to make it clear (your friends do use LaTeX, so I'm assuming math-heavy field):

1. If it is a big burden, then don't sweat it, the possible advantage will be small, other factors will matter much more.
2. Nice resume from Word is better that an ugly resume from LaTeX (in particular if it screams "I can't use LaTeX").
3. Having a nice resume in LaTeX won't hurt, so if it is not a big issue, why not? You could ask your friends to help you (it shouldn't take more than ~2h).

I hope this helps :-)

Comment: Anyone who is capable of doing graduate work in a math-heavy area is capable of learning LaTeX. And perhaps they don't already know it because they've not had any need to write large, math-heavy documents as an undergrad: that seems like a pretty normal situation, to me.

Comment: @DavidRicherby well, plausible, but unusual. I would be surprised to hear of someone who got through an undergrad curriculum in math or physics without ever having the motivation to learn LaTeX, but not so surprised as not to believe it.

Comment: @DavidZ Not unusual at all in my experience.  Even if one has to write up one or two undergrad projects, getting by with Word often outweights the cost of learning TeX.

Comment: @DavidZ FWIW, as a physics undergraduate about ten-fifteen years ago, I don't think there was any point at which anyone even suggested I might want/need to consider learning LaTeX...

Comment: @DavidRicherby There is a difference between _capable_ and _took time to do it_. Such a student surely is capable of doing an internship with some company, but I would prefer one that did (all other things being equal). If I'm hiring for a discrete-maths position, then surely such a student is capable of learning relevant material, but I would prefer one who took time to attend some extra courses in that area. Learning LaTeX takes only two-three days, I would say it is relevant if someone was unwilling to take that time to learn useful tool.

Comment: **Cont.** There surely are other factors, but I strongly disagree with "No. Almost no one cares." And even if people say that it doesn't matter, just as with good looks, it takes conscious effort to enforce that policy on oneself. It's just too easy to take it subconsciously into account. Even if we were to agree that it should not matter, it does matter today.

Comment: @Andrew well, I suppose I can't claim my experience is representative, but I was an undergraduate only slightly more recently, and LaTeX was used extensively by all the students (and, of course, faculty) in my program. There was an implicit understanding that anyone who was serious about it would learn how to create basic documents in LaTeX.

Comment: "It's a bit like being a programmer and not using a version control."  This is extremely common in undergrad.  Generally the situations where it is really needed tend not to occur.

Comment: @Lawtonfogle The exact issue is hard to describe exactly, but it circles around being curious or serious enough or putting enough effort and interest in your studies. If you don't know revision control, then perhaps your hard disk broke too few times, or you never removed a crucial file or didn't collaborate with someone else long enough, etc. If you did all that, if you are curious and serious and put a lot of effort in your studies and still don't know version control, then there should be something else, something extraordinary you did in that time, that trumps all the other disadvantages.

Comment: @dtldarek I don't think many students are running their own servers.  Setting up versioning control doesn't help when it is on the same spot as your hard disk.  For most college use, just copying files over to a backup drive provides better availability.  Combined with most projects being short term individuals (and rarely going beyond a small team in size), there just isn't as much need.  In the same was, there isn't as much need for LaTeX for most undergrads except those already involved in research, and that is a far better selling point than their use of LaTeX.

Comment: There are templates, I don't think it is difficult to use them, so I am not sure if using LaTeX shows some skill...

Comment: @DavidRicherby Anyone who is capable of doing graduate work in a math-heavy area *has already learned* LaTeX.

Comment: @Lawtonfogle I don't think we understand each other. Why do people experiment with new or esoteric languages, even if their usefulness right now is null? I care if the student did such things, because it signals certain curiosity, interest, seriousness, effort, whatever. Lack of any experience with version control is a _strong_ negative signal independent of whether such a tool is actually useful in undergrad (I would argue it is, but that's not my point). Lack of LaTeX familiarity is very small negative signal (almost anything else will take priority), but is not negligible.

Comment: dtldarek: You say that you strongly disagree that almost no one cares about latexed CV's and also "However, for two candidates that are equivalent but for LaTeX, in a math-heavy area I would certainly pick the one with the skill." Could you clarify whether you have ever made a graduate admissions decision in this way?

Comment: @PeteL.Clark Not LaTeXed CV, but LaTeX familiarity. I've never had an occasion to make such decision, moreover, I will take my time before I will allow myself to have such a big impact on someone's else life with so little information (I take such matters very seriously). Yet, it is not so hard to ask (hence my disagreement with "no one cares"), and I have enough personal experience to have at least rough ideas on whom I would like to work with. I dislike putting this in black-and-white terms (surely there are exceptions, right?), but my anecdotal data confirms in 100% what JeffE said.

Comment: @Lawtonfogle: "Setting up versioning control doesn't help when it is on the same spot as your hard disk." I have used version control on several occasions and can recall a couple more in which I would have used it had I known git back then. None of them involves setting up my own server (which I don't know how to do). Basic git skills are sufficient to contribute to any project on github or host one's own project there, and for most academic uses github is a perfectly good place.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark True, I suspect that one would have to review hundreds or tousands of resumes to have a case where such a detail would matter. Still, even if you haven't ever seen such case (thus never acted on the detail), that doesn't mean you don't care. If vote counts were some weak proxy on how many people might care, or even assuming ratios like 1 in 10 or 1 in 20, it is enough to have an incentive to learn LaTeX (assuming no clear better avenues).

Comment: @darijgrinberg  A public github to put your school work on?  Could be risky.  Pay for a private?  Once again the cost vs. risk benefit.  As for working on open source projects, that falls into the same category of 'not that many students actually do that'.  It is a nice bonus, just like having uses a source control tool, but not something that is demanded to graduate (though you could argue it would improve things if it was).

Comment: There is very little risk to a public github. Thieves tend to steal from places that don't have a public history. And I don't merely mean FOSS programming projects; papers and books can be written on github too (e.g., the Stacks project).

Comment: @DavidZ, I completed an undergraduate degree in physics without ever learning LaTeX. Turns out that you can get by with a mix of Word and LibreOffice and various export-to-pdf functionality. I did learn LaTeX eventually, but it's actually because of working with matplotlib of all things.

Answer (score 59):

No. Almost no one cares. You should learn LaTeX if you intend to work mathematics and will need to write up your work. It's much simpler to typeset formulas in LaTeX than MS Word, and it's also free.

Comment: Note that for basic formulas, Word 2007 or later lets you use syntax nearly identical to LaTeX.

Comment: And to expand on this, when creating larger documents (e.g. research papers, book chapters, dissertations, etc) it makes a lot of things easier (formatting, citations, etc) -- not just typesetting formulas.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: @AaronHall: This is definetely an answer, albeit a short one. Comments and answers differ in content, not in length. You may criticise or downvote it for lacking substantiation or being short or similar, if you feel that way, but that does not change that this definetely belongs in the answer domain.

Comment: Even less people would care if the resume would be converted to PDF before submission.

Comment: @enderland Syntax perhaps.  Output no.

Answer (score 19):

To play devils advocate, let me answer **yes**. Of course LaTeX knowledge doesn't imply any other kind of skill, but the two do seem to correlate in mathematical fields, because almost all serious research is typeset in LaTeX.

See Scott Aaronson's 10 tips for detecting if a claimed mathematical breakthrough is wrong (in particular, see #1): http://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/?p=304

Comment: Did Perelman use latex to compose his proof?

Comment: Do you have any actual evidence or experience that typesetting a resume in LaTeX increases its effectiveness in getting a grad school place? Scott Aaronson's article has nothing at all to say about how you should format your resume.

Comment: @DavidRicherby one of my professors once (more-or-less jokingly) remarked "if you typeset your thesis in anything other than LaTeX I will fail you without looking at it" and "if you do not use LaTeX nobody will take you seriously". It is fair to say that to such a professor you would make a bad first impression if your resume is not in LaTeX. Certainly, nobody will care about your resume being in LaTeX, but some people might care about it being in Word.

Comment: @TomvanderZanden I said "evidence", not "anecdote".

Comment: @SalvadorDali: Yes, he did: http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0303109

Comment: I get the feeling that point #1 is somewhat like my own litmus test for the quality of Java code: if you're not using Javadoc, your library almost certainly sucks.  And yet, there are programmers (including a small number of good ones) who disagree as vehemently with my test as I see people disagreeing about the importance of using LaTeX.  I think the ultimate answer is, whether or not using LaTeX is *actually* important, there are plenty of people who feel very strongly that it is.

Answer (score 9):

I think it does not matter so much but the only thing is that it looks more classy than Word documents. Also, you avoid the possibility of file extension issues as your compiled file is already a PDF. If you use Word, possibly, you should convert your file to PDF.

Not really to answer to your question but you can use LyX or find an already made LaTeX template and do it easily.

Comment: I don't care much what application you use for your CV, but if you send me anything other than a PDF I will be slightly annoyed, which is not great for you. When my web site says to send PDF to apply and you send a .docx instead, that's even worse.

Comment: Quite sure that I will not send you my CV, don't worry :-)

Answer (score 7):

Bill Barth says that *no one cares*. And this is true – it doesn't matter what program you use. But I should elaborate that presentation does still matter – you should take care in preparing the document.

Simply using the default layout of *any* typesetting program is generally a bad idea. The formatting is probably not ideal for the purpose, and I have no great love for Calibri and Computer Modern. Sloppy, default formatting may give a bad impression.

Just take the time to carefully design your document layout, and if you want to look a little more distinctive, pick a sensible font such as Palatino or Latin Modern Sans.

If you put a little care into presenting your CV, it should be virtually impossible (without looking at the PDF metadata) to tell which program you used for typesetting. The unique features of LaTeX like `microtype` are not something that people will notice or care about when reading a CV. The `moderncv` package for LaTeX provides some good CV templates, and I suspect there are plenty available for Word as well that look just as good.

Comment: This is the right answer. I _think_ that when I see an academic document written in something other than TeX, I get extremely annoyed---but that's chiefly because when I can _tell_ that it was written in Word, it's generally because the author's put little effort into styling the document (i.e., being nice to the reader). Default vs default, TeX looks better than word; so when I see a well-styled document, I know that the author either (a) cares about the styling (hence my well-being), or (b) knows TeX, and has at least some technical curiosity.

Answer (score 4):

I use LaTeX to typeset my resume *and* my business card. I have typeset it once, and I can go back and modify the content, and as long as I like the overall shape of the document, and I don't have any spelling errors, I know my document is completely free of formatting consistency problems.

Any small change will be immediately applied to all of the appropriate content.

It also allows me to comment out sections and make comments in the source of the document that I use to tell years-older me why I did what I did.

To me, as a LaTeX user, meeting another such user immediately puts them at a higher level than a non-user. To contrast with Barth's answer, with a flat-out, "No." I would say it's a positive signal consistent with the idea  that you can make an investment in learning something, even if not directly related to your discipline, with clear long-run payoffs, and ceteris paribus, I'd rather work with you than someone else with otherwise identical attributes.

But *I* personally value diversity in learning, whereas PhD programs prefer focus.

Overall, it *would* be a **weak** signal and I would not do it simply because you think it makes you look good. Rather, do it because of all the payoffs I mentioned above.

Comment: My math prof typesets all formulas using `\begin{center}$...$\end{center}`, and she's a renowned scientist in her field. Please do not judge people by technical and non-crucial skills.

Comment: A renowned scientist is also miles beyond someone in Word. Sounds like you're agreeing with me?

Comment: No, I don't really agree with you. I'm actually maybe lost in what you state.

Answer (score 4):

Avoid transmitting either of the following messages;

- "This is my first LaTeX document ever"
- "This is my first Word document ever"

... or the morally equivalent "This isn't my first *(X)* document ever, but I have not improved (much) since then".

Other than that, a matter of taste.

This may seem like a bit tongue-in-cheek, but the other answers here fail to address the very real possibility that if you suddenly switch to LaTeX, the outcome will be catastrophic not because of LaTeX, but because you need to learn it before you try to use it.  The same holds for Word, and some people seem never to learn.  Once you're past the "I almost managed to hurt myself with my typesetting software" stage, whatever you use is probably good enough.  (There's "probably" because we cannot predict what sort of nut will be on the reading end.  There will be people who care more than they should.)

Answer (score 2):

I'm an Electrical Engineer that left academia for industry, and typeset my resume in LaTeX. Other than the ease of getting the formatting exactly as you want, there is another benefit: version control. I keep it in Git. All changes are committed no matter how minor. Since .tex files are ASCII, I can diff any two versions I choose. I also have different branches, for example, a grad school application version, and an industry job search version.

Comment: There's no such generalization that ".tex files are ASCII". I think most people today encode their `.tex` files with the UTF-8 format.

Comment: @Sverre, I couldn't really care much less what the actual format it, as long as I can diff them.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should learn latex, regardless of how you intend to write your résumé. As mentioned in other answers, it makes writing math a lot easier, and a lot faster than anything else I've worked with. For academia, it also facilitates writing indexes, sources and basically everything that gravitates around your main narrative.

I would certainly recommend it.

Comment: Welcome to Academia SE, your answer is well-intended advice, but doesn't address OP's original question. Please consider expanding your post.

Comment: I feel like my answer addresses this part of OP's question: "If not, then should I even learn LaTeX for my future academic prospects?"

Answer (score 1):

In average, it does not matter if the content is well-formed and understandable. The latter, by far, is more important.

In opposition to the majority of the answers, **I** find resumes written in LaTeX to be bland. The applicant took a template, wrote the content and printed it out. Please note that I emphasized the "I".

It is strictly a matter of taste of the one who will be at the receiving end. Some people like the standardized, repetitive style (it is often simpler when you go though 1000 resumes) - others are attracted by the slightly more elaborate one which stands out in the heap.

How you present the resume does matter. Since you are just starting I would go for something close to a standard in your field and add some sight deviation so that it catches the eye of the reviewer.

Answer (score 1):

What's important for your CV is that it has an informative layout and that it's easy to read. On top of that, it certainly helps if it looks "nice", whatever that means.

What software you used to create a good-looking CV is entirely irrelevant. I've seen bad-looking CVs and documents written in LaTeX, and I've seen beautiful CVs and documents written in Word. Don't think for a second that an ugly or bland CV in LaTeX will help you in any way.

Focus on creating a good layout for your CV, and use whatever software you think is best suited for you to reach that goal.

As an example from real life, I don't think many people would be able to tell from a print-out of [my CV](http://folk.uio.no/sverrej/cv/stausland.johnsen_cv.pdf) that it was written in LaTeX and not in Word, and I don't think anyone cares either way.

Answer (score 0):

If you're worried simply spend an hour or two playing with [Lyx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LyX), or one of the other [TeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_TeX_editors) editors. It won't take long to pick up the basics / create a TeX variant of the document.

I suggest starting with a GUI based editor, as I personally found it far easier to play in WYSIWYG mode, and then peek at the resulting markup than: RTFM, play in vi, compile and eventually use a Dvi Viewer of your choice to verify the results.

It's a shame [TechWriter](http://www.mw-software.com/icon-tech/Products/TechWriter/TechWriter%20pro.html) was never ported, as 20+ years back it was by far the best TeX based editor around.